# C++ Repeating an inquiry with a user's input

Tags: visual-c++, if-statement, input, while-loop

What I am trying to do is ask a simple question, using 1 or 2 as yes or no for inputs. If they say 1 or 2, then it will continue on with the code. But If they say a number (7) or character ('q'), then the question will repeat again. I haven't figured out how to repeat the question and input.
This is what I have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int answer = 0;

do
{
cout << "Are you Bald? Yes(1) or No(2)?" << endl;
cin >> answer; cout << endl;

    if (answer == 1)
    {
        cout << "You Are Bald." << endl;
    }

    else  if (answer == 2)
    {
        cout << "You are not bald." << endl;
    }

    else { cout << "Please Input proper answer" << endl << endl; 
} while (answer < 1, answer > 2);
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    int answer = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        cout << "Are you Bald? Yes(1) or No(2)?" << endl;
        cin >> answer; cout << endl;

        if (answer == 1)
        {
            cout << "You Are Bald." << endl;
            break;
        }

        else  if (answer == 2)
        {
            cout << "You are not bald." << endl;
            break;
        }

        else 
        { 
           cout << "Please Input proper answer" << endl << endl; 
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it ends up repeating the question even if 1 or 2 is inputted.